# Why there are so many cron.#### files in my home directory?

Tags: cron

In my crontab, I have 2 simple cron jobs running (result of running `crontab -l`):

```
*/5 * * * * wget http://dev.mywebsite.com/specialurl >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * wget http://www.mywebsite.com/specialurl >/dev/null 2>&1
```

`/specialurl` doesn't output anything, and also it doesn't generate any files, and has no application errors.

When I do `ls -l` in my home directory, I see a long list of files, like so:

```
...
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser   myuser       0 Nov  2 22:25 cron.95561
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser   myuser       0 Nov  2 22:25 cron.95561.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser   myuser       0 Nov  2 22:30 cron.95562
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser   myuser       0 Nov  2 22:30 cron.95562.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser   myuser       0 Nov  2 22:35 cron.95563
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser   myuser       0 Nov  2 22:35 cron.95563.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser   myuser       0 Nov  2 22:40 cron.95564
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser   myuser       0 Nov  2 22:40 cron.95564.1
...
```

These files contain no content.

What are these files? Why they are being created? How to fix this?

P.S: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wget's fault. It creates a file by default. In order to get rid of these files you need to use a wget flag to get rid of the output. Something similar to `wget -O /dev/null http://www.mywebsite.com/specialurl`

You can also see if the `-q` option works for you. I seem to recall that the `-q` wasn't enough sometimes

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the main issue! I replaced wget with curl (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187453/134824)) and it worked perfectly fine